# Sort list of list of objects

Tags: java-8, comparator

I want to sort the list of elements based on the list of value inside it.

```
class Response {
List<Group> groupList;
Integer sequenceNo;
}

class Group {
Integer discount;
List<String> rates;
}
```

Looking to sort ascending `List<Response>` according to the `discount`. Basically, groupList will have single element most of the time, but structure is defined as list. Is it possible with java8 to sort the responseList with group having highest discount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
List<Response> sortedResponse = responses.stream()
                .sorted(comparingInt(response -> response.groupList.get(0).discount))
                .collect(toList());
```